# Declare a Mutable Dictionary (to use addEntriesFromDictionary) in header file

Tags: xcode

I need to use several times:
        [mutableDict addEntriesFromDictionary:dictionary];

I don't know how to declare **mutableDict** in the header file. I try with:

> @property (nonatomic, assign) NSMutableDictionary *mutableDict;
>
> @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *mutableDict;
>
> @property (nonatomic, retain, readwrite) NSMutableDictionary *mutableDict;

And more...

How I must to declare this NSMutableDictionary??

Answer (score 0):

In your header file use `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *mutableDict;` if your are **not** using ARC, or `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *mutableDict;` if you are using ARC.

In your implementation include `@synthesize mutableDict;` or better `@synthesize mutableDict = _mutableDict;` somewhere after `@implementation YourClass`.

You should also initialize it with something like `_mutableDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];`

If you do not need your mutable dictionary used from outside (ex: `[myobject.mutableDict addEntriesFromDictionary:dictionary];` you better not define it in your header file but in your implementation like:

```
@implementation YourClass {
    NSMutableDictionary *_mutableDict;
}
```

and initialize it like shown above